# Properly escape characters in a string for JSON

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016, json

With the below example, how do I escape the double-quote characters that are in the @data variable?

```
declare @data nvarchar(max) = N'"TEST"';
declare @jsonFragment nvarchar(max);
declare @id int = 999;

set @jsonFragment = ',"' + cast(@id as nvarchar(16)) + '":"' + @data + '"';

select @jsonFragment;
```

The result is:

```
 ,"999":""TEST""
```

I need it to be:

```
 ,"999":"\"TEST\""
```

As I understand it, selecting `for json path` requires that I define a static key name - but as can be seen, I have a scenario where key names are being defined dynamically.

In my real-world use case, this string construction is occurring within a `stuff` statement, itself part of a column definition in a larger `select` that utilises CTEs - meaning it would be very hard to create a dynamic sql statement to be run using `sp_executeSQL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a system function for this purpose called [STRING_ESCAPE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-escape-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) that will escape the characters as needed for a given string type.

In your example:

```
declare @data nvarchar(max) = N'"TEST"';
declare @jsonFragment nvarchar(max);
declare @id int = 999;

set @jsonFragment = ',"' + cast(@id as nvarchar(16)) + '":"' + STRING_ESCAPE(@data, 'json') + '"';

select @jsonFragment;
```

Returns:

```
,"999":"\"TEST\""
```

It works with all elements that need to be escaped, such as slashes in a pathname, for example:

```
SELECT STRING_ESCAPE(N'C:\PathName\Temp\', 'json')
```

Returns

```
C:\\PathName\\Temp\\
```

Comment: Aha. This sounds like what I'm looking for. My web search skills must suck because I couldn't find it! Will test this when back to my PC. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. So simple. Hope the question helps others find this system function.